# Why am I losing my password param in my user hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I have a simple create method:

```
def create
        byebug
        user = User.create!(user_params)
        session[:user_id] = user.id
        render json: user, status: :created
    end
def user_params
        params
            .require(:user)
            .permit(
                :id,
                :username,
                :first_name,
                :last_name,
                :role,
                :team_id,
                :is_team_lead,
                :avatar,
                :password,
                :email,
            )
    end
```

when I hit the byebug I checked my params:
`#<ActionController::Parameters {"username"=>"User1", "first_name"=>"UserFirst", "last_name"=>"UserLast", "email"=>"abcd@test.com", "is_team_lead"=>false, "avatar"=>"", "password"=>"123456", "controller"=>"users", "action"=>"create", "user"=>{"username"=>"User1", "first_name"=>"UserFirst", "last_name"=>"UserLast", "is_team_lead"=>false, "avatar"=>"", "email"=>"abcd@test.com"}} permitted: false>`

I noticed I lose my password param in the user object at the end. Why would this happen?

Note: I am using bcrypt and my model has `has_secure_password`. I also checked my schema and it has password.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my issue. I didn't wrap my fetch within a user object like:

```
body: JSON.stringify({
                user: {
                    username: userInfo.username,
                    first_name: userInfo.first_name,
                    last_name: userInfo.last_name,
                    email: userInfo.email,
                    is_team_lead: false,
                    avatar: userInfo.avatar,
                    password: userInfo.password,
                },
            }),
```

I also found I could have added this to my UserController to fix the issue as well:

```
wrap_parameters :user,
                    include: %i[
            id
            username
            first_name
            last_name
            role
            team_id
            is_team_lead
            avatar
            password
            email
                    ]
```

Comment: This answer has absolutely nothing to do with the question itself and you should just consider deleting the question as its not likely to actually benefit anyone else.